# Custom time picker in Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I have code to display time picker dialog, and I've made a filter setMinTime and setMaxTime, but I want to filter in more detail.
How can I make filter for today and other date in time picker?

Filter for today:

```
timepickerdialog.setMinTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0, 0);
timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(16, 0, 0);
```

Filter for other day:

```
timepickerdialog.setMinTime(8, 0, 0);
timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(16, 0, 0);
```

Complete code:

```
public void timePicker(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog timepickerdialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
            FormTestDrive.this,
            now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            true);

    timepickerdialog.setMinTime(8, 0, 0);
    timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(16, 0, 0);

    timepickerdialog.setThemeDark(false);
    timepickerdialog.vibrate(false);
    timepickerdialog.dismissOnPause(false);

    timepickerdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
}
```

Comment: Have you provide date selection before time ?

Comment: Yes I input date first with the date picker in other form input

Comment: Based on date selection you can set time picker min and max time for today date or future date.

Comment: dates can be selected from today to 7 days ahead. when choosing today timepicker active from 8.00 AM - 16.00 PM and time will go forward, for example at 10.00, at 8.00 is not active. and for this case i use
timepickerdialog.setMinTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0, 0);
timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(16, 0, 0);
but when choosing the other day I want the timepicker back to normal use this code
timepickerdialog.setMinTime(8, 0, 0);
timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(16, 0, 0);
only at 8.00 - 16.00

Comment: thanks for comment Caresh

Comment: Check date in onDateChanged listener in date picker if date is today then set current hour else default (8-16).

Comment: @HareshChhelana how this code?

Comment: Have you create your custom timpickerdialog ?

Comment: Yes, Complete code above.
DatepickerDialog also already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check selected date from DatePicker is today or not and send today date boolean flag to `timePicker` method as below :

```
new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar selectedDate =  Calendar.getInstance();
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);

                openTimePicker(DateUtils.isToday(selectedDate.getTimeInMillis()));

            }
        }, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Use that today date boolean flag parameter into `timePicker` method as below to set min and max time as below :

```
public void timePicker(boolean isTodayDate){
        int minHour = 8;
        int maxHour = 16;
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimePickerDialog timepickerdialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                FormTestDrive.this,
                now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true);

        if(isTodayDate){
            if(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>8 && now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<16){
                minHour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            }
        }

        timepickerdialog.setMinTime(minHour, 0, 0);
        timepickerdialog.setMaxTime(maxHour, 0, 0);

        timepickerdialog.setThemeDark(false);
        timepickerdialog.vibrate(false);
        timepickerdialog.dismissOnPause(false);

        timepickerdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
    }
```

Comment: TimePickerDialog have not min and max time selection same as DatePickerDialog so you need to validate time after time selected by user in TimePickerDialog listener. Additional TimePickerDialog not disable time as date so you have to handle time selection as above suggestion.

Comment: If choose datepicker today must be here
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c_I4VQEgYTMzq9jY18OYZOKDmELGIqth
but if other day
[link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VsQM76bhmeO-iSXhG7_QUpYrqNJq4fcp

Comment: Today date time slot shown based on current time if time is before 8 then it will shown 8 - 16 and if current time is between 8 to16 then it will shown current time - 16.

Comment: openTimePicker(DateUtils.isToday(selectedDate.getTimeInMillis()));

how to set this code true/false (true if choose datepicker today and false if choose datepicker other day)

Comment: openTimePicker(DateUtils.isToday(selectedDate.getTimeInMilli‌​s())); this code always answer false

Comment: I have true datepicker and timepicker in my case, thanks @HareshChhelana